# How do I parse this data in a Django template?

Tags: python, django

```
{u'4th-of-July': {'name': 4th of July', 'slug': u'4th-of-July'}}
```

I would like to have access to `'name'` and `'slug'` in a django HTML template. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: show your view code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a dict in template with dot notation:

Let's call your dictionary `data`:

```
{{ data.4th-of-July.name }}
```

And

```
{{ data.4th-of-July.slug }}
```

Comment: what if I didn't know that my variable contained u'4th-of-July'? Basically I'm going through a loop and getting values like x = {u'4th-of-July': {'name': 4th of July', 'slug': u'4th-of-July'}}

Comment: @JohnSmith You can iterate over a doct in template with `items` -> {% for key, value in  data.items %}

Comment: Ok did some testing and this worked perfectly. Basically after the loop i did  key.name and was able to get the value I wanted

Comment: @JohnSmith key or value? Keep in mind that in the loop you have the dict in value variable. You can not access the original dict (data) with the variable key -> data.key

Answer (score 0):

Ideally in these cases you should iterate over the keys of the dict. Here is an example:

```
{% for key, value in dict_name.items %}  <!-- where dict_name denotes name of the dictionary containing {u'4th-of-July': {'name': 4th of July', 'slug': u'4th-of-July'}} -->
    {{key}}  <!-- '4th-of-July' for the index 4th-of-July -->
    {{value.name}} <!-- equivalent to dict_name.4th-of-July.name for the index 4th-of-July -->
    {{value.slug}} <!-- equivalent to dict_name.4th-of-July.slug for the index 4th-of-July -->
{% endfor %}
```